# Share Point List Last Modified Date

Tags: list

Ok, so I figured out how to add a row which shows the last modified date, excellent!  However, when I upload new records into my list it shows the last modified date at the date I added the records.  Any way to avoid the initial modified date and only show that date when the record gets modified?

Comment: What do you mean "upload new records"? How do you bring them into your list? Where do they come from? They have their own Modified Date before you add them to SharePoint, and you want to preserve that date?

Answer (score 5):

The Modified column is built-in and you can't change it.
But, you can create a new column to achieve your goal, like this:

1. Create a Calculated column, named "My modified";
2. Type this formula in the Formula box: =IF([Modified]=[Created],"",Modified)
3. The data type is: Date and time; (you can shoose keep date only or with time)
4. Remove the built-in Modified column from your default view, replace it with the new "My modified" column.

Comment: Great solution Jony!