# I want a column, as part of a view that shows the date a file was modified, not including the renaming of the file

Tags: view, view-formatting

We currently have a 2 step uploading process. First we rename the current file on SharePoint, then we upload the new file (this allows us to track usage over the multiple versions).

I am wanting a column that can show me when the second step is done. Which can be achieved by showing the last modified date not including any renaming. Is this possible?

[image: Current View]

Answer (score 0):

See: [Share Point List Last Modified Date](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30418/share-point-list-last-modified-date)

1. Make a new column called "My Modified".
2. Use this formula: `=IF([Modified]=[Created],"",Modified)`. This checks if the file was changed after it was made. If not, it shows nothing. If yes, it shows the date it was changed.
3. Set the type to "Date and Time".
4. Use "My Modified" instead of the normal "Modified" column